# create dynamically widgets python tkinter and adding scroll bar in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new in Python and stackoverFlow.
I am trying to create Checkbox widget automatically from input first column CSV file. How can i get scroll bar in right position. The image below before input the CSV file, scroll bar in the right place

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6e8L.png)

The image below after input the CSV file, checkbox widgets can't be scroll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md9Qm.png)

CODE using python 3.5

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import start
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

LARGE_FONT=("Verdana", 12)

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
"""docstring for MainPage"""
def __init__(self, parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.getColumn = []
    self.createWidgets()


def createWidgets(self):
    self.createPanel()

def createPanel(self):
    nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
    nb.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=50,rowspan=49,sticky="NEWS")
    self.createMainPageTab(nb)
    self.createClassifyTab(nb)


def createMainPageTab(self,nb):
    self.featureSelection = tk.IntVar()

    page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    nb.add(page1,text="Preprocessing")

    selectFileFrame = tk.LabelFrame(page1,text = "Select File")
    selectFileFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5,ipady=5,columnspan=10)

    selectRoleFrame = tk.LabelFrame(page1,text = "select Role")
    selectRoleFrame.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5,ipady=5,columnspan=1,rowspan=1)

    text = tk.Label(selectFileFrame,text="Select The File")
    text.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="E")

    textSelectFile = tk.Text(selectFileFrame,width = 20, height = 1)
    textSelectFile.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="WE",pady=3,padx=5)

    buttonSelectFile = tk.Button(selectFileFrame,text="browse...",command=lambda : self.load_file(textSelectFile,frameCheckBox))
    buttonSelectFile.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="w")

    checkButtonFeatureSelection = tk.Checkbutton(selectFileFrame, text= "Feature Selection",variable = self.featureSelection)
    checkButtonFeatureSelection.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w") 

    buttonCek = tk.Button(selectFileFrame, text='Show', command= lambda : self.var_states())
    buttonCek.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="W")


    #create canvas for scroll bar 
    canvasScroll = tk.Canvas(selectRoleFrame,bg="Yellow")
    canvasScroll.grid(row=0,column=0)

    vBar = tk.Scrollbar(selectRoleFrame,orient="vertical",command=canvasScroll.yview)
    vBar.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="ns")
    canvasScroll.configure(yscrollcommand=vBar.set)

    frameCheckBox = tk.Frame(canvasScroll,bg="blue",bd=2,relief=tk.GROOVE)
    canvasScroll.create_window((0,0), window=frameCheckBox,anchor="nw")

    frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>",self.resize(canvasScroll))


def resize(self,canvasScroll): 
    canvasScroll.configure(scrollregion=canvasScroll.bbox("all"),width=235,height=90)   


def readingCsv(self,fname):
    readCsv = pd.read_csv(fname)
    return readCsv

#event input csv file
def load_file(self,textSelectFile,frameCheckBox):
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("*.csv","Template files"),
                                       ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))
    print(fname)
    mlabel = tk.Label(self,text="%s" % fname)
    mlabel.grid(row=0,column=3)
    # getText=self.textSelectFile.get()
    textSelectFile.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    textSelectFile.delete(1.0,tk.END)
    textSelectFile.insert(tk.END,fname)
    textSelectFile.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    read = self.readingCsv(fname)
    self.getColumn = self.getColumnFromCsv(read)
 #create checkbox
    if self.getColumn:
        for Column in self.getColumn:
            v = tk.StringVar()
            l = tk.Checkbutton(frameCheckBox,text=Column,variable=v)
            l.grid(sticky="w")


def getColumnFromCsv(self,readCsv):
    numeric_variables = list(readCsv.dtypes[readCsv.dtypes != "object"].index)
    return numeric_variables

def var_states(self):
    alabel = tk.Label(self,text="%s" % self.featureSelection.get())
    alabel.grid(row=3,column=0)
    print("tes : %d" %(self.featureSelection.get()))    

def feature_selection(self,chcekFeatureSelection):
    if self.featureSelection.get() == 1:
        pass



def createClassifyTab(self,nb):
    page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    nb.add(page2,text="Classify")
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code. And create shorter example.

Comment: BTW: `bind()` expects callback - it means function name without `()`. Now you assign result from executed `self.resize()` which is `None` - you have something like this `result = self.resize(canvasScroll)` and `frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>", result)`

Comment: thanks for your quick answer @furas, i did your recommendation that took the result = self.resize(canvasScroll), but it still the same

Comment: did you use `frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)` or if you have to send argument `frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.resize(canvasScroll))`

Comment: thanks, it worked properly, u saved my day!!! @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>",self.resize(canvasScroll))
```

which means

```
result = self.resize(canvasScroll)
frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>", result)
```

so you didn't assign function but you executed `resize` and assigned its result.

But `resize` returns `None` so finally you got

```
frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>", None)
```

`bind()` (similar to `command=`) expects callback - it means function name without `()` and arguments - like this

```
frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
```

Because you want to send extra argument (and skip `event` send by `bind` as default) you have to use `lambda`

```
frameCheckBox.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.resize(canvasScroll))
```